# Как отобразить JSON с другого php

Tags: json, php

Привет всем.
Как в своем php отобразить JSON с другого сайта, https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=restuarants+in+sydney&sensor=false&key=Your_API_Key

Через echo будет просто текст.

Comment: Получить, распарсить, отобразить.

Comment: file_get_contents(); всё в одну кучку скидывает, отображала и через echo, и через print_r.

Comment: file_get_contents() - это "получть". А там три пункта. 

Но на всякий случай спрошу: вы ж не пытаетесь результат json_decode() выводить в браузер как есть, прямо через print_r()?

Comment: @Яна Меховская, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: @Яна Меховская, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Полагаю, с file_get_contents будет загвоздка с http**s**

Варианты:

~ Использовать [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) (Не забудьте о **CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER**)

~ Использовать незащищенный протокол (**http**://maps.googleapis.com)

```
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?

query=restuarants+in+sydney&sensor=false&key=Your_API_Key';

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

echo '<pre>'.print_r($data, 1).'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Добрый вечер. 
Если Вам требуется использовать JSON с сайта прямо как структуру, то Вы сначала должна через file_get_contents() с сайта, а потом полученный контент приобразовать в объект с помощью json_decode и работать уже с объектом.

Или Ваш вопрос в другом?