# Написать ajax запрос

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Нужно получить json с городами. Через ajax делаю не выходит. Нашел онлайн инструмент создания http request - всё работает. Вот картинка с сервиса этого[image]

Comment: Без использования php.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько мой скил ванги позволяет, я понял что  вы хотите по api получить json с городами, для этого вам ненужен ajax вам нужно на стороне сервера получить json массив и дальше парсить и работать с ним

вот примерная реализация процесса через штатную функцию php

```
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=restuarants+in+sydney&sensor=false&key=Your_API_Key';

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

echo '<pre>'.print_r($data, 1).'</pre>';// выведет ваш поулченный json
```

к слову пример взят [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/326149/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-json-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-php) почитайте почти ваш случай будет полезно

Answer (score 0):

Запрос из js к внешнему сервису вам помешает сделать ограничение CORS. И это хорошо, это технология, обеспечивающая безопасность.

Вы упоминали в вопросе "Без использования PHP". Правда в том, что вам не обойтись без PHP, или другого аналогичного бэкенд-языка. Схема простая: она описана в [моем ответе к аналогичному вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/556737/217849):

1. Аяксово обращаетесь к своему серверу и проекту;
2. На бекенде в своем проекте обращаетесь к внешнему API;
3. На бекенде получаете ответ и отдаете его аяксово на фронтенд;
4. На фронтенде принимаете в success: function(data)